# Not able to check the database tables for errors

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to check the databases for errors with the hope of improving them if there are any problems.

I have MariaDB 10.3.22 installed on Ubuntu server.

These are the steps that I have followed.

1. login to mariadb using `sudo mysql -u root`
2. the next command `mysqlcheck --all-databases`
3. the results is nothing - I posted it below

> ```
> MariaDB [(none)]> mysqlcheck --all-databases
>     ->
> ```

When I run this command `mysqlcheck --help` at the end of that info I see that values are not set to true. I am not finding any info how to enable them. I don't know this is the cause of that.

Comment: Those are the default values and they get changed by parameters you pass when you execute the command or values in the INI file used by MariaDB/MySQL.